# Is RFC-822 English only?

Tags: rss, rfc822

I'm trying to validate an rss feed and I get an error saying "pubDate must be an RFC-822 date-time".

The date is in Turkish  Sal, 07 Nis 2020 00:05:11 +0000.

If switched to English it validates. But it's a Turkish site...

I haven't been able to find any documentation saying RFC-822 is English only, but nothing with language information either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's intended for consumption by computers more than humans, but the tokens used [in RFC-822](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822#section-5) do correspond to English month and day names.

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed to know :)